# What are the good practices of maintaining feedback from customer support?

Tags: user-research, research, user-feedback, customer-support

In our company we have customer support who deal a lot with users, onboarding, talking, following up and etc. They have a lot of different feedback and insights directly from the users.

**What methods are you using to keep track of everything and filter the feedback?** What are the good practices on this topic? Personal experiences appreciated

Comment: The responses in this post might help: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94013/what-are-the-best-practices-for-keeping-and-analyzing-unstructured-user-feedback/

Comment: Collect the feedback sorted into categories, use general questions if it is no need to add a particular answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a personal experience, but an idea.

Keep a spreadsheet with the following columns:

- name of the person
- company
- date
- feedback
- category / department
- impact (1 - 5, 1 = little, 5 = very high, 0 = none )

Now assign tasks with impact 4 and 5 to the right person via email / PM tool of choice.

You can take up 1-3 tasks after you finish 4,5 tasks.

Do a monthly review to check if any 1-3 tasks have become 4 or 5.

Useful?

Comment: As you seem to mean "name of the person" calling in: Be sure to get their consent if you want to store their interaction. (Yes, i'm from Germany :-)

Comment: I think this goes best for me! Thanks. Personally, I think I will just add a field what actual impact it will make. Increase CR or reduce the amount of users getting confused. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To track and generate insights from qualitative data, I use dovetail https://dovetailapp.com/

I find it really simple to use and adapted to my needs. I sent some comments to their team when they were in beta, and they were really responsive.